# Object hovers above ground surface in ARKit

Tags: swift4, arkit

I placed an object on a plane but its displayed about 10-15 c.m. above said plane.
What code should I have to use for placing **on** the plane?

Here is the code

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/cup.scn")!

// Set the scene to the view
sceneView.scene = scene
```

Here is current scenario screenshot
object is not touching to plane 
[image]

Comment: Your question should at least include some details of what you have actually tried; ideally, some (formatted) code.

Comment: Verify that your 3d object is placed at y-position zero in the .scn. This might not have anything to do with the code you're using to place the object, but rather the 3d asset file itself. If you're building the scene in Xcode, you can check this by clicking on the respective .scn file, click on your node and go to the Node Inspector in the Utilities pane (on the right side). Then check the y position in Transforms. If you're not building the scene in Xcode, then check the y position of your object in your 3d modeling program

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but please check this Code, it may help you

```
    // helicopter is object of SCNNode
    let dragonScene = SCNScene(named: "media.scnassets/helicopter.dae")!
    for childNode in dragonScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        // Adding all the child nodes
        helicopter.addChildNode(childNode)
    }

    helicopter.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.002, y: 0.002, z: 0.002)
    helicopter.position = SCNVector3(x:2.0 , y:0.0, z:-1.6)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(helicopter)
```